# Setting jQuery UI draggable coordinates relative to position of parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a jQuery UI draggable div the is nested within an absolutely positioned div. I am currently using the following code:

```
    $(function() {
    $('#home-elev-door').draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        containment: [2440, 0, 2650, 0]
        });
}
```

This works, however, the containment coordinates I have set are relative to the window. I need to set them relative to the position of the parent div. I tried changing the css position of my draggable element to 'relative' and setting the first containment parameter to 0, but it does not work. What do I need to do?